# Nominate yourself for Freelancing.SE Moderatorship!

Tags: discussion, election

Our [election](https://freelancing.stackexchange.com/election) is starting up (as you may have noticed in the side bar). Currently, we have no nominations. To me, this isn't a good sign. After some discussions on MSE, I decided to write a quick announcement about what to expect:

My day as a mod is not very different from being a user. I sign in each day to check how new questions are doing, answering those I can. If I see a flag, I deal with it to the best of my ability.

Really, it's not a large time commitment. If I run into issues, there are other moderators, both on this site and other SE sites, that can offer advice. If I still don't know what to do, I can reach out to the Community Team for assistance. As a moderator, I'm not ever feeling alone, especially for decisions I make.

If you feel you can handle flags, help new users out, and deal with conflict, then being a moderator could be a logical step forward for you. The flags I typically deal with lately are mostly spam-flags, which other users have already flagged for me to deal with.

Closing questions, offering guidance through comments, and ensuring people understand the rules are all things that can be done with reputation alone. Many users are already doing this.

If you feel you may be a good fit, throw your name forward at [the Nomination Phase](https://freelancing.stackexchange.com/election). If you have questions, please reach out to our current mod team on Meta, and ask.

**It's your community, too!**

Comment: Apparently JohnHC is no longer visiting the site. "Last seen Jul 7 at 11:30".